# Configuring the default behaviour of Super + Tab

Tags: shortcut-keys, configuration

The default behaviour of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is to cycle between open applications, but it starts from the **second** opened application. Is there a way to change this behaviour, forcing it to stay at the **first** application open?

The reason for this is that, usually, I have multiple windows open for a single application in use (i.e. multiple PDFs with Evince) and I want to cycle them while grouped.

The default behaviour of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, which cycles between windows. The latter though makes complete sense, because I don't want to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in the windows where I already am.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2, kernel 5.8 generic, GNOME.

NOTE: This is not a question on setting shortcuts, but changing the default behaviour of the application/thread underlying the command <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to cycle windows of the same application.

If you wish to change the shortcut from <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can do that by going to Settings → *Keyboard Shortcuts* and changing the *Switch windows of an application* shortcut to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (or whichever shortcut you'd like).

[image: Switch windows of an application shortcut]

Comment: That is exactly the behaviour I was looking for! Nevertheless, I am still curious if there is a way to reconfigure super + tab

Comment: Good to know that my answer helped you! Please have a look at my updated answer for how to change the `Super`+`Tab` shortcut.